# Big O notation - estimation of run time

Tags: optimization, arithmetic

I am running very computationally intensive tasks and wish to adjust the parameters respective of how long it takes.

The function I am running is PLINK - for those who don't know, it is used for genotype data.

The function is said to follow a $O(nm^2)$ w.r.t. big O.

I have the run time for two time points with different parameters for $m$ and a constant $n$, they are: 3 hours and 648 hours.

From this I wish to estimate the run-time for different parameters of $m$, that would respect the $O(nm^2)$ relationship.

Can anybody provide some insight as to methods for estimating run-time with the constant $n$ parameters? In other words, we know for run-time function $R$: $R(n_0, m_1)=3$  and $R(n_0, m_2)=648$, and from this I wish to estimate $R(n_0, m)$ for a general $m$; knowing that it follows a growth function $O(nm^2)$.

Comment: If I understand correctly: you have a running-time function $R(n,m)$ whose growth is $O(nm^2)$; you know that for some values $n_0, m_1, m_2$ the outputs are $R(n_0,m_1)=3$ and $R(n_0,m_2)=648$; and you would like to estimate $R(n_0,m)$ for general $m$?

Comment: @Sambo thanks for your response. That is exactly what I meant, yes.

Comment: No problem! You may want to edit your question to clarify it a bit. For writing math on this site, you may want to refer to, e.g., [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: OK. Will edit it now with proper mathematical notation.

Comment: You can't really find running time from big O notation and a couple of data point. Even if you knew your function is from $\theta(nm^2),$ you'd still need more than a couple of data points because your function can look like $a_1nm^2 +a_2m^2 +a_3n^2+a_4nm+a_5m+a_6n+a_7+\cdots$

Comment: I see.. What if I were to run the function many times such that I generate more points? These points however would be at the lower end of the run-time spectrum - e.g. 1 -30 mins. Would it be possible then? And mathematically, how would the estimate be derived?

Comment: Maybe you could make a good enough estimate with just two data points by simplifying your function to e.g. $a_1nm^2 +a_2.$ In this case, you would need to solve a system of equations to determine constants $a_1,a_2.$ Just substitute the values of $n_0,m_1,m_2$ and your running times and solve the system of equations. Then test whether your function gives satisfactory predictions. If not, make it more complex and use more data points.

Comment: @Tom, How was the expression you're speaking of derived? Is it a standard relation to big O w.r.t. the parameters m & n when looking for run-time?

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if $m^2$  were the only relevant changing value, then I could guess your ratio of $m$ values was roughly, 14.7 (sqrt of 216 roughly) . The notation, is mostly used as a way to show a term or set of terms, that approaches the value of the overall function as it's variable(s) get larger. For example: $$4z^2+ 20876549321768543219865740$$ has a relatively huge constant term. But, by $$z=2284543133854.586647726934526$$ that only accounts for roughly half the value of the polynomial. Above this, the term with a variable, starts to take over half. By :$$z=22845431338545.86647726934526$$  the constant term is now at under 0.1 percent of the value of that function. Above this, a good approximation is simply $$4z^2$$ and above $$z=2$$ this estimate is estimated by $$z^2$$. With $n$ constant, your function if large enough to overwhelm other terms will roughly scale with the square of the ratio of $m$ values.